# Is Airflow a good fit for DAG that doesn’t care about execution date/time?

Tags: airflow

The API in Airflow seems to suggest it is build around backfilling, catching up and scheduling to run regularly in interval.

I have an ETL that extract data on S3 with the versions of the previous node (where the data comes from) in DAG. For example, here are the nodes of the DAG:

- `ImageNet-mono`
- `ImageNet-removed-red`
- `ImageNet-mono-scaled-to-100x100`
- `ImageNet-removed-red-scaled-to-100x100`

where `ImageNet-mono` is the previous node of `ImageNet-mono-scaled-to-100x100` and
where `ImageNet-removed-red` is the previous node of `ImageNet-removed-red-scaled-to-100x100`

Both of them go through transformation of `scaled-to-100x100` pipeline but producing different data since the input is different.

As you can see there is no date is involved. Is Airflow a good fit?

**EDIT**

Currently, the graph is simple enough to be managed manually with less than 10 nodes. They won't run in regularly interval. But instead as soon as someone update the code for a node, I would have to run the downstream nodes manually one by one `python GetImageNet.py removed-red` and then `python scale.py 100 100 ImageNet-removed-red`and then `python scale.py 100 100 ImageNet-mono`. I am looking into a way to manage the graph with a way to one click to trigger the run.

Comment: Currently, the graph is simple enough to be managed manually with less than 10 nodes. They won't run in regularly interval. But instead as soon as someone update the code for a node, I would have to run the downstream nodes manually one by one `python GetImageNet.py removed-red` and then `python scale.py 100 100 ImageNet-removed-red`and then `python scale.py 100 100 ImageNet-mono`.. I am looking into a way to manage the graph with a way to one click to trigger the run.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine to use Airflow as long as you find it useful to use the DAG representation. If your DAG does not need to be executed on a regular schedule, you can set the schedule to `None` instead of a crontab. You can then trigger your DAG via the API or manually via the web interface.

If you want to run specific tasks you can trigger your DAG and mark tasks as success or clear them using the web interface.